# как обратить функцию в переменную? чтобы можно было после к ней обращаться и выдергивать file_id

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```py
def save_file(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

        src = 'C:/tmp/' + message.document.file_name
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)

        bot.reply_to(message, "сохраню это")
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, e)
```

Comment: что это за кусок кода?

Comment: телеграмм бот(часть его), в это функция сохранения отправленных юзером боту файлов, мне нужно сделать так чтобы  бот по запросу мог отправлять эти самые файлы юзеры, но как  это реализовать представления не имею, если можете подсказать направление, был бы благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете вернуть из функции file_id:

```
def save_file(message):
try:
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

    src = 'C:/tmp/' + message.document.file_name
    with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)

    bot.reply_to(message, "сохраню это")
except Exception as e:
    bot.reply_to(message, e)
return message.document.file_id
```

Тогда в основном коде вы сможете присвоить переменной file_id и одновременно выполнить функцию:

```
new_file = save_file(message)
```